# UPS doesn't provide any power on battery - Battery broken?

Tags: batteries, ups, testing

I have a [CyberPower CyberPower BR850ELCD-AU](https://www.cyberpower.com/au/en/product/sku/br850elcd) UPS.

[image]

It is a couple of years old and when I tested it a few days ago, I noticed that on battery, i.e. unplugged from power it does not provide any power to its power sockets. Even after leaving the UPS for a day on power it did not work.

Is there an easy way to find out where the problem lies? (Battery?) If so it might be worth it to get a replacement battery.

Comment: First measure the battery voltage. Then measure the battery voltage when it should be charging. That should start to give you an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot say for sure with that model but most UPSes on the market, particularly ones with a display, will self-test on power on and periodically after. This generally includes testing the battery and if the battery is bad, will display an error. There should also be a way in the display menu to display the condition of the battery.

Since you are not getting errors, I'd assume that the problem is not the battery but with the UPS. You could still try a new battery but with these units, the battery is a large part of the cost of a new unit. You'll need to decide.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Very helpful for a none-hardware guy.  I guess something is broken with the electronics.